# How can I get what a user is playing on discord?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, user-presence, user-activity

I'm trying to make a bot (as a joke) that kicks a user when they're playing an specific game, I've been trying to use presence, but can't figure it out.

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
let member = newPresence.member;

if (newPresence != null){
    if (newPresence == 'osu!'){
     member.kick();
    }
}
});
```

This is very barebones, but I need to now what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `newPresence` does not return game value as you are trying to do with `newPresence == 'osu!'`, so it will turn out false everything, also `newPresence` is not string so that is wrong also..

To check what games user is playing or their activity you would need to check

```js
if(newPresence.activities[0].type == 'PLAYING'){
    if(newPresence.activities[0].name == 'osu!'){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The above code is a sample, probs won't even work but you need to check stuff, for example activities might be even null if there is no activity. Please check docs of [DiscordJS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.1.0/class/Presence) to better understand presences

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But it only works before the game is running, not while is running, do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Let's say someone is already playing and then I run the bot, it doesn't work.

But if I run the bot before that user starts playing, then the bot does work.

Comment: `presenceUpdate` event is only triggered when presence is updated, so if the bot starts up and someone is playing already, the event won't trigger. If you want to check if users are playing for example already when you start up the bot, you should utilise the `ready` event which is triggered once bot is booted up, and for example loop through all members and check if they are playing